# Joining over an interim table SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, select

I have a table of rules for pricing. I am retrieving the max discount for each `ProductTypeID`, which indicates which type a product is, using this query :

```
SELECT MAX(discount) as BiggestDiscount, ProductTypeID FROM dbo.SellingPriceRules
WHERE ProductTypeID is not null
GROUP by ProductTypeID
ORDER BY ProductTypeID
```

This works perfectly, however I need to expand on this and, for a list of `ProductID`s retrieve my biggest discount. So I need to find what `ProductTypeID` each `ProductID` belongs to and check my `SellPriceRules` database for the max discount for this `ProductTypeID`.

So, in my `Discounts` table, I have :

```
ProductID, Margin
```

And in my `Products` Table I have :

```
ProductID, ProductTypeID
```

In order to get the ProductTypeID of each product, I have :

```
select * from Discounts m
INNER JOIN Product p on p.ProductID = m.ProductID
WHERE ProductTypeID is not null
```

I am now struggling with joining these two queries together. I simply want to get the max discount for each product in the discounts table and subtract this from my margin. How can I join these two retirevals together?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have all the logic correct.  You just need the syntax of embedding one query inside another.

```
SELECT
  p.ProductID,
  p.ProductTypeID,
  m.Margin,
  d.BiggestDiscount,
  m.Margin - d.BiggestDiscount AS AdjustedMargin
FROM Product p
INNER JOIN Discounts m ON (p.ProductID = d.ProductID)
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    ProductTypeID,
    MAX(discount) as BiggestDiscount
  FROM SellingPriceRules
  GROUP BY ProductTypeID
) d ON (p.ProductTypeID = d.ProductTypeID)
WHERE p.ProductID IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @Annon You have a problem with Index Scan operation on dbo.SellingPriceRules table.http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f986/1

Comment: Given the sample data you are using in SellingPriceRules, I'm not surprised you had problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use correlated subquery

```
SELECT m.ProductID, m.Margin, p.ProductTypeID, 
  m.Margin - (SELECT MAX(discount) 
              FROM dbo.SellingPriceRules 
              WHERE ProductTypeID = p.ProductTypeID)
FROM Discounts m INNER JOIN Product p on p.ProductID = m.ProductID
WHERE p.ProductTypeID IS NOT NULL
```

The execution plan especially for @Annon

[image]

Comment: You are taking a performance hit by using a correlated subquery (which gets refactored to an outer join) when you only need the inner join

Comment: I don't hold with that. First, check it!

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you can use CTE in such situations. Something like this:

```
;WITH current_discounts (BiggestDiscount, ProductTypeID)
AS (
    SELECT MAX(discount) as BiggestDiscount, ProductTypeID FROM dbo.SellingPriceRules
    WHERE ProductTypeID is not null
    GROUP by ProductTypeID
    ORDER BY ProductTypeID
)

SELECT
    m.ProductID,
    m.Margin - c.BiggestDiscount
FROM Discounts m
INNER JOIN Product p ON p.ProductID = m.ProductID
INNER JOIN current_discounts c ON p.ProductTypeID = c.ProductTypeID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this :

```
select *, Margin-BiggestDiscount from Discounts m
INNER JOIN Product p on p.ProductID = m.ProductID AND p.ProductTypeID is not null
inner join (
SELECT MAX(discount) as BiggestDiscount, ProductTypeID 
FROM dbo.SellingPriceRules
GROUP by ProductTypeID) as r on p.ProductTypeID = r.ProductTypeID
```